# Importance weighted autoencoder doing worse than VAE

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning, bayesian-networks

I've been implementing VAE and IWAE models on the [caltech silhouettes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kswersky/data/) dataset and am having an issue where the VAE outperforms IWAE by a modest margin (test LL ~120 for VAE, ~133 for IWAE!). I don't believe this should be the case, according to both theory and experiments produced [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02311.pdf).

I'm hoping someone can find some issue in how I'm implementing that's causing this to be the case.

The network I'm using to approximate `q` and `p` is the same as that detailed in the appendix of the paper above. The calculation part of the model is below:

```py
data_k_vec = data.repeat_interleave(K,0) # Generate K samples (in my case K=50 is producing this behavior)

mu, log_std = model.encode(data_k_vec)
z = model.reparameterize(mu, log_std) # z = mu + torch.exp(log_std)*epsilon (epsilon ~ N(0,1))
decoded = model.decode(z) # this is the sigmoid output of the model

log_prior_z = torch.sum(-0.5 * z ** 2, 1)-.5*z.shape[1]*T.log(torch.tensor(2*np.pi))
log_q_z = compute_log_probability_gaussian(z, mu, log_std) # Definitions below
log_p_x = compute_log_probability_bernoulli(decoded,data_k_vec) 

if model_type == 'iwae':
    log_w_matrix = (log_prior_z + log_p_x  - log_q_z).view(-1, K)
elif model_type =='vae':
    log_w_matrix = (log_prior_z + log_p_x  - log_q_z).view(-1, 1)*1/K

log_w_minus_max = log_w_matrix - torch.max(log_w_matrix, 1, keepdim=True)[0]
ws_matrix = torch.exp(log_w_minus_max)
ws_norm = ws_matrix / torch.sum(ws_matrix, 1, keepdim=True)

ws_sum_per_datapoint = torch.sum(log_w_matrix * ws_norm, 1)

loss = -torch.sum(ws_sum_per_datapoint) # value of loss that gets returned to training function. loss.backward() will get called on this value
```

Here are the likelihood functions. I had to fuss with the bernoulli LL in order to not get nan during training

```py
def compute_log_probability_gaussian(obs, mu, logstd, axis=1):
    return torch.sum(-0.5 * ((obs-mu) / torch.exp(logstd)) ** 2 - logstd, axis)-.5*obs.shape[1]*T.log(torch.tensor(2*np.pi)) 

def compute_log_probability_bernoulli(theta, obs, axis=1): # Add 1e-18 to avoid nan appearances in training
    return torch.sum(obs*torch.log(theta+1e-18) + (1-obs)*torch.log(1-theta+1e-18), axis)
```

In this code there's a "shortcut" being used in that the row-wise importance weights are being calculated in the `model_type=='iwae'` case for the K=50 samples in each row, while in the `model_type=='vae'` case the importance weights are being calculated for the single value left in each row, so that it just ends up calculating a weight of 1. Maybe this is the issue?

Any and all help is huge - I thought that addressing the nan issue would permanently get me out of the weeds but now I have this new problem.

EDIT:
Should add that the training scheme is the same as that in the paper linked above. That is, for each of `i=0....7` rounds train for `2**i` epochs with a learning rate of `1e-4 * 10**(-i/7)`

Answer (score 1):

The `K`-sample importance weighted ELBO is

$$ \textrm{IW-ELBO}(x,K) = \log \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{p(x \vert z_k) p(z_k)}{q(z_k;x)}$$

For the IWAE there are `K` samples originating from each datapoint `x`, so you want to have the same latent statistics `mu_z, Sigma_z` obtained through the amortized inference network, but sample multiple `z` K times for each `x`.

So its computationally wasteful to compute the forward pass for `data_k_vec = data.repeat_interleave(K,0)`, you should compute the forward pass once for each original datapoint, then repeat the statistics output by the inference network for sampling:

```py
mu = torch.repeat_interleave(mu,K,0)
log_std = torch.repeat_interleave(log_std,K,0)
```

Then sample `z_k`. And now repeat your datapoints `data_k_vec = data.repeat_interleave(K,0)`, and use the resulting tensor to efficiently evaluate the conditional `p(x |z_k)` for each importance sample `z_k`.

Note you may also want to use the `logsumexp` operation when calculating the IW-ELBO for numerical stability. I can't quite figure out what's going on with the `log_w_matrix` calculation in your post, but this is what I would do:

```py
log_pz = ...
log_qzCx = ....
log_pxCz = ...

log_iw = log_pxCz + log_pz - log_qzCx
log_iw = log_iw.reshape(-1, K)
iwelbo = torch.logsumexp(log_iw, dim=1) - np.log(K)
```

EDIT: Actually after thinking about it a bit and using the score function identity, you can interpret the IWAE gradient as an importance weighted estimate of the standard single-sample gradient, so the method in the OP for calculation of the importance weights is equivalent (if a bit wasteful), provided you place a `stop_gradient` operator around the normalized importance weights, which you call `w_norm`. So I the main problem is the absence of this `stop_gradient` operator.